# How to remove autofilling of meta descriptiion in Magento 1.9

Tags: meta-description

For SEO purposes, I do not want meta descriptions and meta keywords filled in. I want them blank so Google will choose meta descriptions for search results.

How do I stop Magento from auto filling blank meta descriptions?

Answer (score 0):

there is a special module for SEO

[CreareSEO](https://github.com/adampmoss/CreareSEO)